# Filter dropdown is not showing on Datatable

Tags: html, jquery, datatable

I am trying to filter adatatable column with a dropdown and I followed the steps in the documentation here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

However, my dropdowns are still not appearing at the footer of the table, so I was wondering what was wrong. The table is well initialized with the search and pagination appearing, just not the dropdown.

This is how I initialize the table:

```
//initialize datatable
myTbl = $('#myTbl').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
        
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    },
    columnDefs: [ {
        targets: [0]
    }],
     pageLength: 5,
     language: {
        search: '',
        searchPlaceholder: "Search"
    },
    columns: [{
        data: function(d) { return d['name']}
    }]
});
```

This is how I declare my table in HTML:

```
 <table id="myTbl">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    
        <tbody>
            
        
        
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
           <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
     

      </table>
```

Appreciate any help thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I managed to figure out what was the issue, in case anyone is facing the same issue, I changed 'initComplete' to 'drawCallback' and also added an empty row in the tfoot tag and it works now.

Comment: IDK if the HTML is just your example, but DataTable is not DataTable without data inside. Can you provide any warnings or errors, or if possible jsfiddle?

Comment: hi, I am dynamically inserting rows into this table through javascript. In the 'columns' parameter, that is how I am inserting the rows. I tried hardcoding rows and the rows and everything turns up perfectly well, just that the filter drop down that should be at the footer is missing.